# Is it possible to create lilacs with different colored flowers on different branches?

Tags: grafting, lilac

Is it possible to create (using grafting) a [Lilac (Syringa vulgaris)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syringa) which has different colors? One branch with white flowers, the other with lilac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear you can:

http://www.ehow.com/info_8568761_can-graft-lilac-tree.html

This page is specific for lilac trees and includes some grafting advice. In particular, quote:

> Functions of Grafting
>
> Grafting brings new cultivars to an existing tree to introduce another
>   variety while a cutting can be grafted
>   to a new seedling to bring strength to
>   the new planting. Planting a grafted
>   lilac branch can lead to a new bush
>   altogether.

The list of expert answers has a number of references to lilacs reverting to their rooting stock colour:  (ie. multiple colours are possible on the same plant via grafting)

http://www.ext.nodak.edu/extnews/hortiscope/shrub/lilac.htm